# xcode 4 build settings descriptions

Tags: xcode, build, xcode4

In Xcode 3, when you click on a build setting, a small description appears at the bottom window briefly describing what the setting does.  How do I view the equivalent in Xcode 4 without having to google each setting whenever I need to change it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open the Utilities area and set it to the Quick Help tab (Command-Option-2).